# Nest ko.component inside of component.template

Tags: knockout.js, nested, components

I am trying to build my jquery based tree viewer library with knockout.js (https://github.com/davewood/treejo)

I built a component and want to use the component in its own template.

Almost working but then I got weird errors when the nested component was initialized.

This JSFiddle demonstrates the problem if you open the console. http://jsfiddle.net/tyx89ude/8/

I had to copy&paste knockout.js into the javascript window (scroll down to see my code) because if I loaded knockout via jsfiddle the ko.components function wasn't available.

```
ko.components.register('node', {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        console.log(params);
        var self = this;
        self.title = ko.observable(params.title);
        self.url = params.url;
        self.body = ko.observable(params.body);
        self.classes = ko.observable('node node-closed');
        self.children = ko.observableArray(params.children);
        self.load = function () {
            var data1 = {
                'title': "title1",
                    'body': "body1",
                    'url': "url1"
            };
            var data2 = {
                'title': "title2",
                    'body': "body2",
                    'url': "url2"
            };
            self.children.push(data1);
            self.children.push(data2);
            self.classes('node node-open');
        };
        self.children.subscribe(function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
    },
    template:
        '<div data-bind="css: classes">\
            <div class="node-panel">\
              <div class="node-heading">\
                <a class="node-toggle" data-bind="click: load">&gt;</a>\
                <span class="node-title" data-bind="text: title"></span>\
              </div>\
              <!-- ko if: body -->\
              <div class="node-body" data-bind="text: body"></div>\
              <!-- /ko -->\
            </div>\
            <div class="node-content" data-bind="if: children().length > 0">\
              <div data-bind="attr: { title: title }" class="node-closer"><div></div></div>\
              <div data-bind="foreach: { data: children(), as: \'child\' }"></div>\
                <div data-bind="component: { name: \'node\', params: child }"></div>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
          </div>'
});
```

Update: correct JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tyx89ude/26/ thank you Vlad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a mistake in your template mark-up

Change:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: children(), as: \'child\' }"></div>\
```

To

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: children(), as: \'child\' }">\
```

Comment: Are you kidding me! Thank you so much. As I am new to proper JS development my toolchain is far from perfect and that I missed this stupid mistake is a symptom of that. That's the result of not having html syntax highlighting due to using string literals in js for template development.